# sum tow numbers from different sheet via google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

i use this code

`function sumValue(){
 return "=Sum(Sheet1!f8,Sheet5!C1)"; 
}`

to add to number from sheet1 and sheet5. but i want to remain that sum result to the same cell(Sheet5!C1) how can this code be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already in the script editor, we could just use more features of app script, because in your case, formula makes thing more complicated:

```
function sumValue() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var valueofSheetOne = spreadsheet.getRange("Sheet1!F8").getValue();
   var valueofSheetFive = spreadsheet.getRange("Sheet5!C1").getValue();
   spreadsheet.getRange("Sheet5!C1").setValue(valueofSheetOne + valueofSheetFive);

}
```

Comment: there are all good people in stack overflow, Carr you made good solution

Comment: @Negativeplus, I'm glad it's helped, welcome to the community, and maybe you could 'accept' or 'vote' the answer matching your question